# Table not showing border in PDF in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am generating PDFs in Laravel but table is not showing borders border property is there but not working.

I am fetching data from database which includes table also but unfortunately not showing border.

this is my table tag

```
<table class=MsoNormalTable border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%"
 style='width:100.0%;border:1px solid red;mso-border-alt:solid windowtext .25pt;
 mso-border-top-alt:solid windowtext .75pt;mso-yfti-tbllook:1184'>
```

Please help

Comment: Which package you're using for pdf?

Comment: i am using mpdf

Comment: Use inline style on table to set border.

Comment: yes its already there because i am getting data from data base and css is there in Content.

Comment: You are passing attributes without double quotes like in `border=1` and also in class attribute.

Comment: Sharukh as you have said i have added border using inline css and it works fine thanks.but border not showing in cells only table border not applying on cells.

Comment: apply border on td

Comment: hii Sharukh as you said i applied some conversion to remove and add inline border but i am getting an error.

Comment: Errro:   invalid characters passed for attempted conversion these have been ignored in

Comment: $data = str_replace('border:none','border:1px solid #000',$data);

            $data = str_replace('border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;','border:1px solid #000',$data);
            $data = str_replace('border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;','border:1px solid #000',$data);
            $data = str_replace('border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;','border:1px solid #000',$data);